# Need to install dont no how BRAND NEW

Tags: system-installation

I am brand new to linux and basicly I want to install Ubuntu 14.4 and dual boot with windows 8 please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the install process...

~You'll be asked to pick a username and password. 
.....When you pick the username, the name of your computer will automatically appear also.

~Then it will ask you to pick a password.
.....You'll be asked for this many times when you use Ubuntu, so if there's no one else who has access to your system, you might want to make it short, 
.....on the other hand, for security reasons you might want to make it strong - 8 characters or more, not your SS#, bank info, and no recognizable names or words.

~Then it will offer 3 choices:
1. log in automatically,
2. Log in with your password,
3. I think it's 'log in remotely?'

.....For ease and speed, I'd pick 'log in automatically,' 
.....but again, depending on how security conscious you are, you may want to pick #2.

~Next it will ask you if you want it to partition your disk.

~There will be a line with a slider for you to move to pick the size of the partition that you want for each OS.
.....Windows is heavy on resources, so I'd use a somewhat larger partition for that.

~Then go on with the install. I think at this point it doesn't ask any more questions but just runs itself, giving information about Ubuntu as it does.

~Finally it asks you to restart your system, and there you are.

~When I had my drive partitioned and I started my system, a prompt would appear asking me which partition I wanted to start. Just arrow up or down for Ubuntu or Win 8.

If I've missed anything, folks, please correct me, but I think this should do it.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much so I use the wubi thing In the iso?

Comment: Don't use wubi!  It's deprecated!  Use the link above your question!